# Algorithm negotiation fail - JSchException:

Tags: java, session, aes, jsch

I am getting below exception when my application tries to connect to particular switch.

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
```

Connection to other switch is possible but, one particular switch fails.
What can be possible reason?
I am getting exception at this line of code:

```
session.connect(30000);
```

Output of my logs:

```
null Connecting to NDELEVDA0001 port 22
null Connection established
null Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2 FIPS
null Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.43
null CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
null aes256-ctr is not available.
null aes192-ctr is not available.
null aes256-cbc is not available.
null aes192-cbc is not available.
null arcfour256 is not available.
null SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
null SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
null Disconnecting from NDELEVDA0001 port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
```

Comment: + You are using an ancient version of JSch, you need to upgrade.

Comment: But, other switches are getting connection. so how come jsch version affect only single switch? :(

Comment: + What is duplicate of jsch algorithm?

Comment: Because that switch is has probably a different version of OpenSSH.

Comment: Your question is duplicate of the question linked in my first comment.

Comment: Issue is resolved. I had imported jsch 0.1.54 jar but it was not picking the correct jar. 

Issue is resolved by upgrading the jsch jar